# Any way to repair the protective screen film on an old Fujitsu Stylistic LT C-500 Tablet?

Tags: repair, tablet

I have a 10-year old tablet computer that I picked up for a song a few years ago. It works fine for me as a wireless webcam server.

It uses a stylus and eventually I scratched the protective film letting in air bubbles, now the film is slowly separating from the device.

*picture here:*

[image]

Is the film replaceable/repairable in a DIY fashion or is it a goner? I hate to toss working tech but it's certainly not worth sending out for repair.

**NOTE:** The computer itself still works great, but the screen surface is no longer smooth and further stylus use just snags on the breaks and bubbles in the film.

**UPDATE:** It turns out the protective film is not just the thin sheet but the thicker plastic underneath as well. The adhesive is old enough to just pull up now. I tried this unsuccessfully a few years ago and stopped, thinking I might break it. A little alcohol on a cotton swab to clean away the last bits of dried adhesive and I'm good to go! Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to search eBay, maybe there are some protective films for this model there. If not, then find a device with the same, or bigger screen size and trim it to fit.

ED:

I've found several on [eBay](http://shop.ebay.com/i.html?_nkw=fujitsu%20C-500%20screen&LH_PrefLoc=2&_fln=1&_trksid=p3286.c0.m283) for ~23.50 USD. Probably you can find it on amazon too, if you prefer it.

Answer (score 1):

You can buy [replacement films](http://www.photodon.com/c/FJS.html) for products like this.